# Set a Variable from an Imported List of Servers with Select-Object

Tags: powershell, foreach, select-object

Currently I have the below script that works however I have over 30 servers and  they often change so i was curious if there was a simpler way to get the `$ServerList` variable updated with the import data from each of my servers.  The server path is the same and I could maintain a `Server.txt` file with all the server names.  Any ideas on how to simplify this to work with a larger list of servers that I can update when needed without having to add lines to the powershell script?

```
$Headers = "Extension","Server IP","Comment"
$1 = Import-Csv "\\Server1\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header $Headers | Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={'Server1'}}
$2 = Import-Csv "\\Server2\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header $Headers | Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={'Server2'}}
$3 = Import-Csv "\\Server3\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header $Headers | Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={'Server3'}}
$4 = Import-Csv "\\Server4\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header $Headers | Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={'Server4'}}

$ServerList = $1,$2,$3,$4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Get-Content](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113310) cmdlet to get a list of servers (you have to create the `Server.txt` first). Then you can use the [Foreach-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113300) cmdlet (alias `%`) to iterate over it and use the current server:

```
$Headers = "Extension","Server IP","Comment"
$servers = Get-Content 'Your_path_to_server.txt'
$ServerList = $servers | 
    % { $server = $_; Import-Csv ("\\{0}\app\test\Stations.txt" -f $server) -Header $Headers | 
    Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={$server}} }
```

Now you don't need to change anything on the script if you add a server.
Here is the same script but maybe a little better to understand for you:

```
$Headers = "Extension","Server IP","Comment"
$serverNames = Get-Content 'Your_path_to_server.txt'

$ServerList = @()

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames)
{
    $ServerList += Import-Csv "\\$serverName\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header "Extension","Server IP","Comment" |
     Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={$serverName}}
}
```

Comment: The format operator is needless in your first code snippet. You even removed it on the second.

Answer (score 0):

A method I would use for something like this would be to make a Function for it.  Here's some untested sample code.

```
Function Import-ServerListCSV($serverName){
   $Headers = "Extension","Server IP","Comment"
   Import-Csv "\\$serverName\app\test\Stations.txt" -Header $Headers | Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={$serverName}}
}

$ServerList = "Server1","Server2","Server3","Server4" | % {Import-ServerListCSV $_}
```